# Change child directive's attribute from a parent directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form directive that needs to communicate with a form-sections directive to tell it to change is layout. The change is triggered by a form-header directive.

```
<form>
  <form-header></form-header>
  <form-sections></form-sections>
</form>
```

I injected the form directive's controller in the form-header, so that the header can call the changeLayout function.

form directive:

```
compile: function(scope, element , attrs) {
    element.find('form-sections').attr('current-view', 'tabs'); // initial layout
},
controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {                
  this.changeLayout = function(layout) {
    $element.find('form-sections').attr('current-view', layout);
  };
}
```

form-sections directive:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  attrs.$observe('currentView', function(currentView) {
    console.log('observe:'currentView);
  })
}
```

$observe is triggered only once, by the form directive's compile function, but not by it's controller. I tried it with an isolated scope in the form-section directive and use $watch, without any success..

Thanks as always!

Comment: Look into priorties and compiling - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2794-when-do-you-need-to-compile-a-directive-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: The changeLayout function is called at runtime when everything is compiled.

Comment: did you tried with `someVariable: '='` two way binding & then put watch on variable

Comment: Yes I did, the only way that I see how to do it would be if I recompile the form-section directive